# Foundamental group of the cylinder by triangulation and Stong Theory

Tags: algebraic-topology

If we build a triangulation of the cylinder (compact), that triangulation is a simplicial complex by definition. So, there is a Kolmogorov Space associated to that SC that is also a finite topology, and this is builded by simplex incluson. By this, there is a graph associated to this finite topology. Studying the lineal and colineal points of this graph (Stong theory) we can reach a retract of the graph that represent this topology erasing those points a building the new graph keeping the order relation (that is, reaching the core). This core must be a graph that represent the Fundamental Group of a circunference (that is, a "square" formed by 4 vertices).

With that, starting with the habitual cylinder triangulation (picture) and doing the usual, the core of the graph associated to the triangulation don't represent Z at all, and I don't really know where i'm failing. Can somebody help me, please? [Triangulation of the Cylinder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACDS9.png)